# C: Adding integer to char pointer(address)

Tags: c, char-pointer

I am getting from a function a pointer to the (empty at the start) data of a block.

This pointer is:

```
char* data;
```

And my job is to insert different types of data in this block. I know only the data type (string/int/float) and their length in bytes.

For example, for an inserting integer, I want to give to each block a form like:

```
|block_num|age|weight|favorite_number|
```

So my main question is, how can I insert the number to the block and get them like? I would like smth like data[3] to get weight each time.

I have tried to use memset and memcpy, but there was no success.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You want to store an `int` in an address pointed by a `char*`?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want your function to return something that could be of different types (string/int/float/etc..). Working with basic pointer 'char*' and then casting is considered not type-safe. I would suggest you to define abstract base class that will hold 'a data' and define several several pure virtual methods for this class. Your function should return base-class pointer that will be used in polymorphic way.

Comment: @PazO.: You talking about `C`?

Comment: @coderredoc: I am talking about C++ implementation

Comment: @PazO.: OP asked the question under `C` tag.

Comment: @coderredoc yes, and getting it back as int

Comment: @PazO i am talking about C, my mistake, fixed! thanks

Comment: @coderredoc: Sorry, missed this. In this case I would advice to do the equivalent in C: define struct with enumerator that says 'who I am' and according to this cast the structure to other structure.

Comment: @NickSt are the values separated by '|' in char array ?

Comment: @NickSt you may need to parse the data string ?

Answer (score -1):

In case you want to write to an address pointed to by a `char*` you need to cast it to proper type (that you want) and de-reference it.

For example: (here `returnedFromFunc` is similar to your `data`).

```
char *returnedFromFunc = func();
```

you can write an `int` by properly casting it to `int*`

```
*((int*)(returnedFromFunc))=intValue;
```

To go to the next location you would simply do this:-

```
char *originalPtrValue = returnedfromFunc; // store it for future referece
returnedfromFunc += sizeof intVar;
```

Similarly you can access it also if you know the type of data you are storing.

For example if it is `int`

you can do this

```
printf("%d ", *((int*)(returnedFromFunc)));
```

Using the `sizeof` operator you can access different locations.(offseting from the initial `char*` value).

You need to know how much memory is there where you can write. Otherwise there is a chance that you might try to write into memory that you have no permission to.(out of the bound )